# How to append date and time in boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-rds

I am trying to append date and time in aws rds snapshot name but not able to get this working. This is how i tried to specify

```py
import json
import boto3
import botocore
import logging
import os

from datetime import datetime
from operator import itemgetter

rds = boto3.client('rds', region_name='eu-west-2')

# set initial vars
source_db_instance="source-database"
target_db_instance="target-db"
location="eu-west-2"

logger = logging.getLogger(name=__name__)
env_level = os.environ.get("LOG_LEVEL")
log_level = logging.INFO if not env_level else env_level
logger.setLevel(log_level)
waiter = rds.get_waiter('db_snapshot_available')

rds = boto3.client('rds', region_name='eu-west-2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

# Get the current date and time
now = datetime.now()

# create a reformatted date / time var
current_date = now.strftime("%d%m%y")
# create a snapshot name by combining the date time and database name
from_snapshot_name=("my-" + source_db_instance + "-" + "refresh" + "-" + 
current_date)

try:
    print("Trying to delete aource snapshot if it exists")
    del_response = rds.delete_db_snapshot(
    DBSnapshotIdentifier=(from_snapshot_name)
    )
except:
    print("")

try:
    print("Taking snapshot")
    response = rds.create_db_snapshot(
    DBSnapshotIdentifier=(from_snapshot_name),
    DBInstanceIdentifier=(source_db_instance)
    )
except:
    print("")
```

After executing the above in lambda function. i get the snapshot created but it doesnt include the date and time at the end

Comment: There's very little context here, please show us more of the code and format it as Python code so its readable.

Comment: @Maurice just updated the full code

Comment: @Maurice Any idea what am i missing here

Answer (score 0):

I had to redeploy the lambda function. Its sorted

Comment: Good to know that you got it working! If this problem cannot be reproduced, feel free to Delete the question since it won't help future readers.